# How to fix wrong cultural infos in azure?

Tags: .net, azure

Even though i am using the right region for the WebApp, its displaying the wrong time format and currency. So how can i change the region in order to fit my country (Germany).

I have tried to change the plan to a different region. Didnt work (used us before and changed to eu west)

Comment: Deploying a web app to some azure region doesn't change you app's culture. You have to do it in your code or configuration.

Comment: Look at [globalization cultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) to set `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture`

Comment: If i start the app on my local machine it uses the correct region. I know that i can set the region in code but i want to be able to deploy to multiple regions without code changes. Isnt it supposed to do exatly this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you, refer [Implementing custom cultures, CultureInfo, localize Azure App Service for more details](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/06/11/implementing-custom-cultures-cultureinfo-localize-azure-app-service/).

Here you can find all the supported culture list:

http://customcultures.azurewebsites.net/

just deploying the code to the region wont help . you can use i18N though to implement it.

The i18n library is designed to replace the use of .NET resources in favor of an easier, globally recognized standard for localizing ASP.NET-based web applications.

you can find the sample [here](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n). Hope it helps.